# Exclude directories with 'rsync' and ssh with pull request

Tags: rsync

I am trying to pull from a remote server and exclude a directory on the remote server. For some reason it keeps pulling that directory I have excluded.

Here is the command I am running:

`rsync -azP --exclude=/home/xxxx/public_html/batchupload root@xxxxx.com:/home/xxxxx/public_html /var/www/xxxxx/public_html`

I have also tried:

`rsync -azP root@xxxxx.com:/home/xxxxx/public_html --exclude=/home/xxxx/public_html/batchupload /var/www/xxxxx/public_html`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is that rsync sees the path names as being relative to the source directory.  So, for example, if I'm syncing this directory:

```
$ ls /home/me/foo
bar  baz
```

Then the file paths it knows will be like `foo/bar/...` and `foo/baz/...`.  If you add the verbose flag to rsync, you'll see things like:

```
public_html/foo
         277 100%    0.56kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#1390, to-check=0/1393)
```

Try just:

```
rsync -azP --exclude=public_html/batchupload root@xxxxx.com:/home/xxxxx/public_html /var/www/xxxxx/public_html
```

Comment: You were right about the relative path. In the example you gave it does not work with `--exclude=public_html/batchupload`. However `--exclude=batchupload` does work .